# Hangindent in Custom Environment created with tcolorbox's many Option

Tags: indentation, tcolorbox

I wish I could be more specific, but being that I don't understand all of the underlying stuff that's happening, my question will have to be vague (hence the awkward title, I'll edit it to be more specific once I know the details), sorry.

**Question:** Why does `\settowidth{\hangindent}{some text}` not work inside my `lemma` environment (which is, I think, created using the `many` option from `tcolorbox`)?

(I've tried to adjust the `\parindent`, that used to fix some issues with indentation in other tcolorboxes I used, but apparently not here.)

Thanks in advance!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
% Packages used
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
% Counter (probably unrelated)
\newcounter{lemmacounter}[chapter]
\def\thelemmacounter{\thechapter.\arabic{lemmacounter}}

% Where the problem probably lies
    % lemma command for lemma environment using tcolorbox (somehow, I'm not really sure how this is working), with optional "name" argument
\DeclareDocumentCommand \lemma {o} {%
    \IfNoValueTF {#1} {%
        \noindent\refstepcounter{lemmacounter}\colorbox{black!10}{\textbf{L-\thelemmacounter}}\itshape %
        \settowidth{\hangindent}{L-00 }\hangafter=1 % Why does this not work?
    }{%
        \noindent\refstepcounter{lemmacounter}\colorbox{black!10}{\textbf{L-\thelemmacounter}}\textbf{ (#1).}\itshape
        \settowidth{\hangindent}{L-00 }\hangafter=1 % Why does this not work?
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Some Lemma]
    Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by changing your definitions slightly, here it is:

```
\newenvironment{lemma}[1][\empty]{\begingroup
\if!#1!\noindent\refstepcounter{lemmacounter}\colorbox{black!10}{\textbf{L-\thelemmacounter}}\itshape
\else%
\noindent\refstepcounter{lemmacounter}\colorbox{black!10}{\textbf{L-\thelemmacounter}}\textbf{ (#1)}\itshape\fi
\settowidth{\hangindent}{L-00 }\hangafter=1%
}{\par%this does the trick for the hangindent
\endgroup}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which works nicely; however, could I ask you what the error was in the original code, i.e. why it didn't work? (Also, a small irrelevant edit I can't make, it should be `(#1). `.)

Comment: @ABlueChameleon Glad to hear that my advise helps you, and I already mentioned \par does the trick, if you give \par at the end of the paragraph manually, then your coding also works...

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that was particular to the new code. Then that's solved too. Thank you!